# What is the mean of "typosquatting"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I read an article this morning and I dont understand what is the mean of "typosquatting" excactly?

I have alread use some dictionaries but I could not find what I want.

The article : https://seld.be/notes/typo-squatting-and-packagist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typosquatting, also known as **URL hijacking**, is a form of cybersquatting (sitting on sites under someone else’s brand or copyright) that targets Internet users who incorrectly type a website address into their web browser (e.g., “Gooogle.com” instead of “Google.com”).

> When users make such a typographical error, they may be led to an
>   alternative website owned by a hacker that is usually designed for
>   malicious purposes.

*What is cybersquatting ?*

[image]

**Reference :**
https://blogs.mcafee.com/consumer/what-is-typosquatting/